# Blazor Custom AuthenticationStateAsync call after startup fails because of JavaScript

Tags: blazor

I've got Blazor server side program where I implemented own Authentication with reading Token from JavaScript.

Works fine - except on startup, where the Reading fails (of course, because server side rendering needs OnAfterRender for JavaScript calling).

But here the code is executed by Blazor itselfs and throws exception.

How can I fix this, that this call won't be make or run on other runtime (after rendering)?[image]

Thx

Answer (score 1):

JSInterop can be accessed only after your app has been rendered, not before.
To solve this issue you need to call the TokenStorageService.GetToken from the OnAfterRender or OnAfterRenderAsyn methods of your components. Here is a code snippet to demonstrade this:

```
@page "/mypage"

@inject TokenStorageService tokenService 

@code{

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsyn (bool firstRender)
  {
     // Ensure that the app has been rendered, and it is the first 
     // render. Note also that this code is only executed once. And it
     // won't be executed on recurring calls to the OnAfterRenderAsyn.
     // This makes it an ideal place to initialize JavaScript objects.
     if(firstRender)
     {
         var token = await TokenStorageService.GetToken();
     }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your reply. I already knew this, but as you can see in Screenshot - the code is coming from internal Blazor "Host.ExecuteAsync"... so I can't handle there anything. 
This comes probably because I use CascadingAuthenticationState, but I need to for using Login functionality...